# I am not able to copy the downloaded windows istaller

Tags: 12.04

I downloaded the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Windows Installer on my desktop.
Now am not able to copy it to my external hard disk. It gives an error 'low disk space, delete some files and try again' even though i have 200+ GB space on the disk

Answer (score 0):

Will you please check the .trash folder in your external hard drive. Pressing CTRL+h shows all hidden folders in your hard drive.

I also got the same problem once, there was lots of items in the .trash folder of my external hard drive.

Hope this helps.